# Are there any side effects to drinking alcohol?

Tags: dishonored

What's the effect of drinking alcohol?

Does it refill the life gauge?  Are there any side effects (such as troubled vision or troubled controls) by drinking a certain amount of it?

[image]

Comment: Blackouts, nausea, sweating, shaking, incontinence, uncontrollable urge to discuss politics, inability to assess personal capability to sing and/or dance, lowered inhibitions, embarrassing Facebook photos... sorry, couldn't resist.

Comment: I'm almost sad those are not part of the game :(

Comment: you forgot drunk dialing exes and telling them you are so much better off without them then starting to call incoherently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried drinking from the Sparking Wine Fountain (which is an unlimited source of wine and can be drank multiple times) found in the [Lady Boyle's Last Party](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Lady_Boyle%27s_Last_Party) mission, and can confirm that it does restore some of your health (and in that mission, [it can also be used to fulfill an optional objective](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Lady_Boyle%27s_Last_Party#Guests)). This leads me to believe that alcoholic drinks are like any other food item in the game - they just restore some health.

I tried drinking it multiple times but have not noticed any negative side effects such as troubled vision or controls.

> <sup>Looks like The Outsider has granted Corvo with a very useful power.</sup>