# How do people commit suicide?

Tags: path-of-exile

We were playing, a friend and I, fighting hordes in [Warehouse Sewers](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Warehouse_Sewers), when suddenly...

[image: Suicide]

I swear he's not suicidal at all (even if he's playing a gloomy Shadow).  We didn't understand what happened.  Any idea ?

Comment: Whatever your troubles may be, suicide is not the answer. You are not alone, please call 1-800-273-8255.

Comment: I was *so* waiting for something like that :D  It reminds me of this one: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90386/are-there-any-side-effects-to-drinking-alcohol#comment124625_90386

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any skill or affix that will lower your life under 0 will cause you to "suicide" yourself.  Some examples:

- [Blood Rage (green gem)](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Blood_Rage) (-4% life per second)
- [Blood Magic (red support gem)](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Blood_Magic_%28support_gem%29) (spend life instead of mana for linked skills) (will not activate skill if hp is to low)
- [Blood Magic (passive skill)](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Blood_Magic) (spend life instead of mana for every skill)
- [Flasks' Caustic mod](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Flasks#Modifiers) (- X% of mana recovery from life on use)

Comment: I'm pretty sure spamming stuff while running Blood Magic kills you as well. Might add that in (^u^)

Answer (score 15):

There are flask mods that reduce your health (i.e by 15%) on use. Take it with low health and you suicide.